# Can I do this with an IQueryable<T>?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

is it possible to add an extension method to `IQueryable<T>` and then, for my Linq2Sql or EF or NHibernate or LinqToObjects, define it's functionality / how each repository will impliment this method / translate this method to some sql?

For example, imagine I want the following :-

```
var result = (from q in db.Categories()
              where q.IWishIKnewHowToCode("hi")
              select q).ToList();
```

now, the code for the extension method `IWishIKnewHowToCode()` will differ when it's L2S, compared to EF or LinqToObjects, etc.

I'm not talking about a Pipes and Filters, here. That I know how to do that.

So imagine that, if this was L2S, then that method would do a linq `Where` clause but if the repository was .. say ... LinqToObjects, it would do a `Take(10)`.

Is this possible?

(I'm not too sure what it's officially called ... about what I'm wanting to do)

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to create an extension for IQueryable<T>.  In your example, it seems that you would want to create an extension method for the type T.  And you can create an overload for each type T.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep, you're missing something here. Type <T> is a POCO class. It knows nothing a persistence/repositories. IQueriable<T> can know about persistence/repositories, in each repository project/layer. As such, i'm hoping to generate a Queryable expression .. and each persistence project will have to explain how to impliment that Extension Method (keyword), against it's dependant repository. Eg. If the keyword is 'IWishIKnewHowToCode' .. then for a L2S repository against sql server, this would be a where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty evil, but the closest I can think would be to special-case the provider:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static IQueryable<T> IWishIKnewHowToToCode<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> data, string something)
       // perhaps "where T : SomeBaseTypeOrInterfaceForThePredicate"
    {
        switch (data.Provider.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "Foo": return data.Take(10);
            case "Bar": return data.Where(somePredicate);
            default: return data;
        }
    }
}
```

(obviously there are other ways to switch on `Type`).

Then use via fluent syntax (not query syntax):

```
var result = db.Categories().IWishIKnewHowToCode("hi").ToList();
```

Comment: I was hoping to NOT have the to provider known at this level, but implimented only INSIDE each providers namespace. Bascially, this extension method would be *persistence ignorant* and each persister/repository would then impliment the logic, how it see's fit. (my Take/Where examples where extream examples, used above .. by design). Does that make sense, Marc?  (and thanks heaps for reading my question).

Comment: Also Marc, i found this blog post by you, interesting and relevant to this question: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/pragmatic-linq.html  . Relating to this post, i *think* i'm trying to generate my own expression which will generate it's own SQL? (i hope i've used the correct terminology, here).

Comment: I don't think either is possible (in a generic way). LINQ-to-SQL allows you to issue custom TSQL, but not as part of an `Expression`. EF allows you to issue custom ESQL (a different syntax), and again not AFAIK as part of an `Expression`.

Comment: So what i really wanted to do, Marc, was to create an INLCUDE(string) extension method, and this will do a dataload for L2S and Include() in EF ... So you think it cannot be done?